# Meteor.js : best way to stop event propagation

Tags: javascript, meteor

Consider this template in Meteor.js.

```
<template name="trial">
  <li id='{{ _id }}'">{{ name }}
    <span>X</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

I want to add an event to the "li" and another one to the "span". How can I prevent the click on the span to fire the event attached to the li? I've found some posts talking about this, but they're years old.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Show what you already tried so far and then community will be able to answer you, if you was right, wrong, or how far you are from the best/optimal solution.

Comment: Not familiar with meteor, but have you tried good old `event.stopPropagation()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent event from bubbling-up to parent elements, use `stopPropagation()` of the event object. Works on either native JS events, or React events:

```
spanClickHandler(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // handle click
    ...
}
```